# How to resolve "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in javascript"?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a D3.js example.

It works fine on [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/V6Qr8/), however when I try the same code locally it starts throwing the following error:

"**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

update

loadImage

onclick**"
[image: Here's a screenshot of the same]
If you check the fiddle above, the  functions are  like this:

```js
var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    node,
    path,
    root, nodes, links;

var force, vis;
var LoadData = true;

function update() {
    if (force) force.stop();
    nodes = flatten(root);
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .linkDistance(120)
        .charge(-500)
        .start();

    path = vis.selectAll("path.link");
    path = path.data(force.links());
    path.exit().remove();
    path.enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
    vis.selectAll(".node .simpleDiv").remove();

    node = vis.selectAll(".node");
    node = node.data(force.nodes());
    node.exit().remove();
    node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", click)
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("class", "simpleDiv")
        .attr("width", function (d) {
        var f = document.createElement("span");
        f.id = "hiddenText";
        f.style.display = 'hidden';
        f.style.padding = '0px';
        f.innerHTML = d.name;
        document.body.appendChild(f);
        textWidth = f.offsetWidth;
        var f1 = document.getElementById('hiddenText');
        f1.parentNode.removeChild(f1);
        return textWidth + 50;
    })
        .attr("overflow", "visible")
        .attr("height", 50)
        .append("xhtml:div").attr("class", "mainDiv").style("cursor", hoverStyle)
        .html(function (d) {
        var htmlString = "";


        var userImage = "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6fN48PEP2-z-JbutdhqfypsYdciYTAZEziHpBJZLAfM6rxqYX";
        if (d.type == 'user') {
            htmlString += "<div class='userImage' style='border-color:" + color(d) + "'><image src='" + userImage + "' width='36' height='36'></image></div>";
            htmlString += "<div class='content' style='color:" + color(d) + ";'>" + d.name + "</div>";
            htmlString += "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
        } else if (d.type == 'chat') {
            htmlString += "<div class='docIcon'><i class='icon-comment icon-3x'></i></div>";
            htmlString += "<div class='content' style='color:" + color(d) + ";'>" + d.name + "</div>";
            htmlString += "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
        } else if (d.type == 'message') {
            htmlString += "<div class='docIcon'><i class='icon-file-alt icon-3x'></i></div>";
            htmlString += "<div class='content' style='color:" + color(d) + ";'>" + d.name + "</div>";
            htmlString += "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
        } else {
            htmlString += "<div class='docIcon'><i class='icon-exclamation icon-3x'></i></div>";
            htmlString += "<div class='content' style='color:" + color(d) + ";'>" + d.name + "</div>";
            htmlString += "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
        }
        return htmlString;
    });
}

function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function (d) {

        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + (d.x - 15) + "," + (d.y - 15) + ")";
    });

}

function color(d) {
    return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

function hoverStyle(d) {
    return d._children ? "pointer" : d.children ? "pointer" : "default";
}
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update();
}

var findNode = function (node) {
    for (var i in force.nodes()) {
        if (force.nodes()[i] === node) return true
    };
    return false;
}

    function flatten(root) {
        var nodes = [],
            i = 0;

        function recurse(node) {
            if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
            if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
            nodes.push(node);
        }

        recurse(root);
        return nodes;
    }

    function loadImage() {
        if (LoadData) {
            root = {
                "name": "physics",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "type": "user",
                    "children": [{
                    "name": "DragForce",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1082,
                        "type": "user"
                }, {
                    "name": "GravityForce",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1336,
                        "type": "user"
                }, {
                    "name": "IForce",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 319,
                        "type": "user"
                }, {
                    "name": "NBodyForce",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 10498,
                        "type": "user"
                }, {
                    "name": "Node 1",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "type": "user",
                        "children": [{
                        "name": "DragForce 1.1",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "size": 1082,
                            "type": "chat"
                    }, {
                        "name": "DragForce 1.2",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "size": 1082,
                            "type": "message"
                    }]
                },

                {
                    "name": "Particle",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 2822,
                        "type": "user"
                }, {
                    "name": "Simulation",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 9983,
                        "type": "user"
                }, {
                    "name": "Node 2",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "type": "user",
                        "children": [{
                        "name": "DragForce 2.1",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "size": 1082,
                            "type": "message"
                    }, {
                        "name": "DragForce 2.2",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "size": 1082,
                            "type": "message"
                    }]
                },

                {
                    "name": "Spring",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 2213,
                        "type": "user"
                }, {
                    "name": "SpringForce",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "size": 1681,
                        "type": "user"
                }, {
                    "name": "Node 3",
                        "imageURL": "",
                        "type": "user",
                        "children": [{
                        "name": "DragForce 2.1",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "size": 1082,
                            "type": "chat"
                    }, {
                        "name": "DragForce 3.2",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "size": 1082,
                            "type": "chat"
                    }]
                }]
            };

            force = d3.layout.force()
                .on("tick", tick)
                .size([w, h]);

            vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
            update();
            LoadData = false;
        }

    }
```

```css
circle.node {
    cursor: pointer;
    stroke: #3182bd;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
path.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #666;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.simpleDiv {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
}
.simpleDiv .mainDiv {
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
.simpleDiv .mainDiv .userImage {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius:30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.simpleDiv .mainDiv .docIcon {
    width: 36px;
}
.simpleDiv .mainDiv .content {
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
#hiddenText {
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<input type="button" name="loadImage" value="Load" onClick="loadImage();" />
```

I had properly loaded the D3.JS file and the Javascript code for that example in proper sequence.

I also tried using *this* keyword but I didn't get the result. (May be I have used it incorrectly, I would really appreciate if some one could suggest proper reference usage of *this* keyword in this example).

Thank You

Comment: 2 cases might be present, 1. couple of semicolons might be missing 2. you haven't loaded all the files(or in proper order).

Comment: Case 1: Semicolon missing - I have just copy pasted it (and I did it twice to be sure). i have not edited the code so I think semicolon should not be the case. Case2 : Loading files & their order. I have loaded all the files correctly. there are just 2 files to be loaded D3. JS & actual JS code. I loaded D3.js first, so order is also not an issue.

Comment: is D3 dependent on Jquery? can you show me a screenshot of error?

Comment: No D3 isn't dependent on Jquery. (Still I had tried including the jquery, it had no difference on the o/p.). Also  you can confirm through the JS Fiddle that it has not loaded Jquery (Check the dropdown, it says "No library.Pure JS). And  the functions for which it was giving error are the defined functions in JS code and not jquery ones. The issue seems to be with the referencing i guess.  Btw I have added the screenshot of error to my  question. Thanks :)

Comment: can you paste the code for index.html?

Comment: It goes like this: <html>
    <head>
      
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
 
       <script src="JS/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  
       <script> /* The long JS Script which I have specifieded in the ques */ </script>    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
     
        <button onclick="loadImage()" name="loadImage" >Load</button>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry for pasting like this. There is no formatting help in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Because jsFiddle automatically imports all the necessary libraries. Have you imported them all? Was the import correct? You need at least this: [enter link description here](http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js)

Comment: Yes, the import was correct and I had added the D3.js file. I also cross checked it on console by caling out its functions.